# How can I map a relationship in nHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

#### Schema:

- Users

  - ID
  - Name
  - Password
- Address

  - ID
  - Street
  - UserID

Both tables have an ID field (guid).

#### Code:

```
User u = new User();
u.Address.Street = "test";
session.Save(u);
```

How can I create a mapping file to use the `UserID` from the address table to point
to the ID from the `Users` table and reflect my sample code above?

---

Using many-to-one i sucessfully solve my problem.

but i go search more samples!!

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of the cases, such kind of mapping should lead to a 'component'.
In your case, Address could be a component of User.
This means that you'll have indeed an Adress class, and the User class will have a property of type Adress, but the Address is saved in the Users table in the DB.

If you really want a one-to-one mapping with the DB layout like you want, I suggest you create a one-to-one mapping in the User mapping, and a many-to-one mapping in the Address mapping (with unique set to true).   But, I think that this also means that you will be responsible of deleting the old address first if you update the adress of a user ...

Comment: This is working to save my two objects:

User.hbm.xml


  <class name="SCI4.Domain.User, SCI4" table="User">

    <id name="Id" type="string">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="uuid.hex" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name"></property>
    <property name="Password"></property>
    <property name="Type"></property>
    <one-to-one name="Address" class="SCI4.Domain.Address" cascade="all"/>
  
  </class>

Comment: Address.hbm.xml:

  <class name="SCI4.Domain.Address, SCI4" table="Address">


    <id name="Id" type="string">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="uuid.hex" />
    </id>

    <property name="ZipCode"></property>
    <property name="StreetType"></property>
    <property name="Street"></property>
    <property name="Number"></property>
    <property name="Neighborhood"></property>
    <property name="State"></property>
    <property name="City"></property>
    <property name="OwnerId"></property>
  
  </class>

Comment: this tag is my problem, howto i fill then with the user.id value???
<property name="OwnerId">